# Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDB-DynamoDBMapper'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

When I run my Spring Boot 2.0.0 application with the current latest version of [spring-data-dynamodb](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb) (v5.1.0) I get the following error at runtime.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamoDB-DynamoDBMapper': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.config.DynamoDBMapperFactory]:
>   No default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.config.DynamoDBMapperFactory.()

I have tried the following things:

1. Adding a DynamoDBMapperFactory bean to my configuration class and making it primary
2. Different combinations of AWSCredentials, DynamoDBMapperConfig, DynamoDBMapper and AmazonDynamoDB bean configurations (e.g. removing them, making them primary, giving them names and explicitly referring to them)
3. Different combintations of config passed to the EnableDynamoDBRepositories annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that spring-data-dynamo v5.1.0 was not compatible with my version of Spring Boot (2.0.0)

Downgrading the spring-data-dynamo library to v5.0.4 fixed my issues.

Comment: My dude you asked and answered this so quick. You are a beacon of light. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue by using the `dynamoDBMapperConfigRef` option of `@EnableDynamoDBRepositories`. Adding the code snippet below,

```
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(dynamoDBMapperConfigRef = "dynamoDBMapperConfig")

@Bean
public DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig() {
    return
        DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder()
            .withTableNameOverride(withTableNameReplacement(tableName))
            .build();
}
```

This is working even with the latest version of spring-boot and spring-data-dynamodb.

There is an Open issue raised in Github. You can also check this link, [Second instance of DynamoDBMapperConfig being created](https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/233#issuecomment-462186444)